# Vim script for automatic function insertion

Tags: code-generation, header-files, vim, ex

Say I have a class `evilLord` declared in the file `evil_lair.hh` and is implemented in the file `evil_lair.cc`. Now, I want to add the function `bool minionDo(std::string command)`. Is there any script which will put the declaration and empty function definition in the respective files automatically?

I am using `c-support` vim-plugin which I find useful. Maybe this can be added as a functionality to this script...

Answer (score 1):

The task is not that trivial -- if we want to correctly report the scope of the function. I've already done the work in my `:GOTOIMPL` (and `:MOVEIMPL`) command, from my [lh-cpp ftplugin suite](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script which will work:

```
:let lines = ["bool minionDo(std::string command)"]
:e evil_lair.hh
:call append( line('$'), lines )
:wq

:e evil_lair.cc
:call append( line('$'), lines )
:call append( line('$'), "{}" )
:wq
```