# vim autowrite functions in header file. C lang

Tags: c, vim

I tried to use `vim` for c program editing. Is there a way to auto write function skeleton defined in header file?

situations like

```
"my_code.h"
int temp(int*);
```

and "my_code.c"
    <<< here  auto write >>> like

```
int temp(int*) { return }
int main()
{
}
```

I'm using `c.vim` plug-in. I tried to find it, but I couldn't make it.

Comment: BTW, your question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844817/vim-script-for-automatic-function-insertion . But I gave a more up to date answer today, plus there are other interesting answers related to snippets engines (however I fail to see how they answer your exact question). That's why I don't flag your new question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

[There are code completion scripts, yes.](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Automated_Text_Insertion). However, this is not something you generally want. It works for simple things like basic C functions, and fails horribly beyond that (i.e. templates etc in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)). You don't save any time by using such plugins, and mastering [vim](/questions/tagged/vim) motion/yank/paste commands provide the same result in the same amount of time, and you become more familiar with a modal editor. Is it **that** hard to copy-paste the function prototype and add some braces `{`/`}`?

If you want something to help as a reminder to write function definitions to go with function prototypes, consider using the `taglist` plugin.

[image]

[image]

Comment: what font are you using ?

Answer (score 2):

*snippets* are like the built-in `:abbreviate` on steroids, usually with parameter insertions, mirroring, and multiple stops inside them. One of the first, very famous (and still widely used) Vim plugins is [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) (inspired by the *TextMate* editor); unfortunately, it's not maintained any more; though there is [a fork](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate). A modern alternative (that requires Python though) is [UltiSnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715). There are more, see [this list on the Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Automated_Text_Insertion).

There are three things to evaluate: First, the features of the snippet engine itself, second, the quality and breadth of snippets provided by the author or others; third, how easy it is to add new snippets.

---

Additionally, there are also *template* plugins that pre-initialize a new, empty file with a skeleton, often including a file header and copyright statement. Search [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/); you'll find plenty.

Answer (score 0):

I've have a `:GOTOIMPL` command in [lh-cpp](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp/) that generates an empty function definition from a function declaration.

However, you'll have to execute the command on each function declaration and go back to the header file. I've never took the time to batch the process from an header file and no implementation file -- as this is not a use case I have as there exist other solutions...

IOW... there exist projects that do the job from the command-line (and which you could call from vim then) (like for instance https://github.com/Davidbrcz/header-expander), or even other plugins (like protodef: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2624).